# php exec and cpanel terminal issue

Tags: php, terminal, cpanel, shell-exec, whm

i have a server that have 2 hard drive, i have install cpanel on home directory and some of website are in home2

also my server is cent os 7.9

now my issue is when install for example ffmpeg on server, site on home can use it in php shell_exec but site in home2 can't use and get error command not found

i add user of site in home 2 to wheel group and if i connect using ssh ,it work with ffmpeg command but if i try using shell_exec or cpanel terminal it's return command not found error

what is the problem? can any one help?

Comment: also i found user in home 2 have different /usr/bin path than user in home directory

Comment: each home directory connect to an hdd